# execute an app when a button from another app is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

basically my question is if its possible to listen the click event from another app no matter how its programmed and then execute mine (using c#), i made some examples using the spy++ utility with .net, and i know it is possible using the user32.dll and kernel32.dll, libraries that managed this kind of functions

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a windows hook, see [link1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx)[link2](http://win32assembly.online.fr/tut24.html)
[link3](http://duke2.sunjapan.com.cn/~hz/win32/hooks32.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) It might help you get there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detect when a click is made to run an application, you must detect when a particular application is launched. you can do this using two ways.

1) using the WMI check the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class and the  [`ExecNotificationQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393864%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

2) using the [PsSetCreateProcessNotifyRoutine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, this function adds a driver-supplied callback routine to, or removes it from, a list of routines to be called whenever a process is created or deleted.

additionally  you can check this question [`How to Recognize that an Application Intends to Execute \ Run a File ?!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489501/how-to-recognize-that-an-application-intends-to-execute-run-a-file)