# Notification when a program is loaded

Tags: shell, delphi, notify

Is there a way to receive notification (in Delphi), when any program is loaded or run ?

Comment: The answer to your immediate question is, yes, there is a way. Did you mean to ask how to do it? Which platform? Windows?

Comment: Doing a quick search, I'm not finding anything in the WinAPI to explicitly get notified of this. However, you *could* repeatedly get a list of currently running processes, and compare the new list with the last list: http://forum.codecall.net/topic/72604-getting-running-processes-list/ However this wouldn't be accurate for a process which started and terminated in a split second, for example.

Comment: Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489501/how-to-recognize-that-an-application-intends-to-execute-run-a-file ?